# Php, array of objects, get all classname of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = new Class1();
$array[] = new Class2();
$array[] = new Class3();

var_dump ($array); // returns the objects
var_dump (array_values($array)); // same as above
var_dump (array_keys($array)); // returns empty array
```

I want something which returns with ['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3'], so a `get_class()` on each object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each element of the array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) an call [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) on it)

```
var_dump (array_map("get_class", $array));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Class1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Class2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Class3"
}
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: No need for that, upvote will suffice :-)